# Closing Excel from Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have the following bit of code which opens up an Excel sheet, carries our some procedures and then shuts the sheet.

I am having trouble shutting the sheet!

```
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWorkBook As Object
 Dim path As String
 Dim osh As Shape
 Dim filename As String
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


 path = "path"
 filename = "Name.xlsx"
 xlApp.Visible = True
 Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
 Set positionsheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
 Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

 'does stuff here

 ActiveWindow.Visible = False

  With xlApp          ' I think the error is here!!!
    .xlWorkBook.Save
    .xlWorkBook.Close
 End With
```

For some reason the sheet doesn't close! Any ideas??

Comment: try this xlworkbook.close

Comment: or this Sub Close (
 SaveChanges As Object,
 Filename As Object,
 RouteWorkbook As Object
)

Comment: without the xlApp. infront of it?

Comment: your first recommendation worked Cheers!

Comment: sure, make sure you accept the answer it helps the others who faced the same problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
xlworkbook.close
```

Answer (score 0):

The `With`-Block throws an error, since xlWorkBook is not a parameter of xlApp.

This works in my test:

```
' ...
'does stuff here
'NoWith Block!
xlWorkBook.Save
xlWorkBook.Close
xlApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object
    Dim Sht As Object
    Dim xlStarted As Boolean
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Path = "C:\Temp\"
    FileName = "Book1.xlsx"

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlStarted = True
        xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path & FileName)
    Set Sht = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'does stuff here

    '// Close & SaveChanges
    xlWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    If xlStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```